# Opengl front to back blending issue (black screen)

Tags: opengl, draw, alphablending

I'm implementing a renderer where the shading requires front-to-back rendering. I'm having issues figuring out how to initialize the blending function.

Here's what I tried.

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS); 
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA, GL_ONE);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

This results in a black screen.

[The blog post](http://hacksoflife.blogspot.no/2010/02/alpha-blending-back-to-front-front-to.html) says to use GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA, GL_ONE and initialize the background to all black all translucent, which is what I think I'm doing. The post cites [an nvidia whitepaper](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/5_Simulations/smokeParticles/doc/smokeParticles.pdf) so I looked into that as well. I looked through the code there and they seem to do somewhat the same as me. However something is clearly wrong as it isn't working. If I don't use blending or use other blending functions things seem to work.

**EDIT:**

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
glutCreateWindow("Window");
```

Comment: Did you request your framebuffer to have an alpha component, and check that you actually got it?

Comment: Hey, i havent done any more initialization than i put in the code there. I just render directly to the default framebuffer

Comment: What framework/toolkit are you using to set up your context and window? The format of the default framebuffer is specified during this initial setup. The details are highly platform/toolkit/framework dependent.

Comment: i'm using freeglut to create the window and context

Comment: Can you add the initialization code to the post, particularly the `glutInitDisplayMode()` call?

Comment: @RetoKoradi Added them now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specifically request alpha planes during your GLUT initialization if you use blending that involves destination alpha. Change the call to:

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_ALPHA);
```

You might think that specifying `GL_RGBA` would be sufficient. At least I did, until I just checked the [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node12.html), which says:

> Note that  GLUT_RGBA selects the RGBA color model, but it does not request any bits of alpha (sometimes called an  alpha buffer or  destination alpha) be allocated. To request alpha, specify  GLUT_ALPHA.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_ALPHA); now, but unfortunately the screen is still back when I use 
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA, GL_ONE) instead of glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA).

Comment: Ops, clearcolor was 0,0,0,1 when i tried. It's working.